# Force responsible for compression of extended spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Suppose there is a free spring (there is no mass attached to it ). Next , I apply a force "$f$" to it and extend it's length to say x from mean position. Now, I hold  the spring at that position. At length $x$ the spring force (on me by spring) $= -Fx$ (-ve because directed towards mean position ) and by Newton's $3$rd law I apply a force $Fx$ on the spring. Now as soon as I leave the spring the spring accelerates and return to mean position. What's the cause of that acceleration ? Now due to absence of my force does spring apply a force on itself (as I thought a particle can't apply a force on itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought a particle can't apply a force on itself.

Correct, but it's better to consider the spring as a collection of particles, that transmits the force applied by wherever the spring is attached to (which allowed you to extend the spring in the first place) through each other.

> Suppose there is a free spring (there is no mass attached to it )

To conduct this reasoning using Newtonian mechanics you'll need to suppose that your free spring is massive, since the formalism doesn't include massless objects ($\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$).

Answer (score 0):

If you pull on a spring to extend it, I assume the other end must be attached to something like a wall.  When you let go of that spring, the force of the wall on that spring will cause the acceleration toward the wall.

If you are talking about pulling on both ends of the spring and then let go, there will then be no net external force and there will be no acceleration of the center of mass, but the spring will vibrate in place.